# Kendo grid cell edit

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I have a kendo grid in column user can edit . I am using editor and datachange even firing to server for validation if inavid data then revert to previous value. Everything working fine but unable to revert to previous value as of now clearing field. Can anyone help me on this

```
dataChange:function(changedatta)
{
   If(changedatta.column name==="abc")
   {
       // do something
   }
}
```

Comment: You should post a bit of your code so people will be able to help.

Comment: You're not really using this snippet on your real app, right? Cause that isn't a valid Javascript code.

Comment: Further, I don't know any `dataChange` event in any Kendo widget, even on [Grid](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/grid#events).

Comment: I am using real but column name is different